# Why isn't this control saving the result's back to the database?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

Here is the *child* form:

[image]

Here's the code behind it:

```
public partial class uxFormDatabase : Form 
{ 

BindingSource rawtableBindingSource = null; 

public uxFormDatabase(BindingSource myPassedSource)  
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    rawtableBindingSource = myPassedSource; 

    uxDGVtable.AutoSize = true; 
    dataToDGV(); 
} 

public void dataToDGV() 
{ 
    uxrawdataBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.rawtableBindingSource; 
    uxDGVtable.DataSource = this.rawtableBindingSource; 
} 

private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Validate(); 
    rawtableBindingSource.EndEdit(); 
} 

}
```

I was under the impression that when `uxFormDatabase` is activated the method `public uxFormDatabase(BindingSource myPassedSource)` fires which passes the BindingSource in from the parent form;

If that is the case then why when I press the save button 'saveToolStripButton_Click', on the BindingNavigator are the changes not getting saved back to the database? Do these two lines not save changes back to the databse `Validate();rawtableBindingSource.EndEdit();` ?

**UPDATE**

The above form is loaded from this *parent* form:

```
namespace WindFormAppRevisionHelper
{

    public partial class uxRevisionHelperForm : Form
    {

        public SqlCeConnection conn = null;
        public SqlCeDataAdapter da = null;
        public DataSet ds = null;
        BindingSource definitionsBindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public uxRevisionHelperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        uxDescriptionTextBox.AutoSize = true;
        refreshBindingSource();
        assignControlsToSource();
    }

    public void refreshBindingSource()
    {            
        conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindFormAppRevisionHelper.Properties.Settings.DefinitionsDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(new SqlCeCommand("Select * From tb_RevisionDefinitions",conn));
        ds = new DataSet("Study Helper");
        ds.Tables.Add("DefinitionsTable");
        da.Fill(ds.Tables["DefinitionsTable"]);

        // Assign the BindingSource.
        definitionsBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables["DefinitionsTable"];
        uxBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.definitionsBindingSource;

    }
    void assignControlsToSource() 
    {
        uxDescriptionTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", definitionsBindingSource, "Description", true));
        uxWordPhraseTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", definitionsBindingSource, "WordPhrase", true));
        uxReferenceTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", definitionsBindingSource, "Reference", true));
    }

    private void uxUpdateDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = false;
        uxBindingNavigator.Hide();
        uxFormDatabase myNewDisplay = new uxFormDatabase(definitionsBindingSource);//<<<<this loads the _child_ form
        myNewDisplay.FormClosed += delegate { activateGroupBorder(); };
        myNewDisplay.Show();    
    }

    public void activateGroupBorder() 
    {
        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = true;
        uxBindingNavigator.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you load your BindingSource? Probably you miss the DataAdapter.Update(tablename) call.

Comment: @TheZ I'm intrigued by your comment; can you expand it a bit?

Comment: @Steve - the BindingSource is loaded when the main parent form is loaded. Do I need to load it again in the `saveToolStripButton_Click` method?

Comment: No, I just wish to see how do you load it. Probably, you use a DataAdapter. This DataAdapter should call Update() to save data.

Comment: @Steve ok - I've updated the OP...no `Update()` in the code; what syntax do I need to use and where in the code is it best to place it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) you can see that, the SqlDataAdapter object used to prepare the binding source, is responsible of the database update.

I think you could pass to the constructor of your `uxFormDatabase` also the `SqlCeDataAdapter da`, save it in a global instance var inside your `uxFormDatabase` and then, after the `Validate` and `EndEdit`, call `da.Update((DataTable)rawtableBindingSource.DataSource);`

Code used:

```
    private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        rawtableBindingSource.EndEdit();
        SqlCeCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(rawtableDA);
        rawtableDA.Update((DataTable)rawtableBindingSource.DataSource);
        cmdBuilder = null;
    }
```

Comment: steve - when you say "global instance var" do you mean in a similar way to the way I've declared the bindingsource? ... `BindingSource rawtableBindingSource = null;` ...Ok so I can convert the DataSource to a DataTable.

Comment: alright Steve - had chance to test now. It is getting to the Update line and throwing an error `Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows`

Comment: Try to use a [SqlCeCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x83wx3z(v=vs.80)). Just before the Update call. This will create the UpdateCommand for your table inside the table adatapter.

Comment: Great; thanks for the help Steve; can I edit your answer with the code that seems to work?

Comment: Yes, please do it and I will approve.

Comment: tell you what Steve; in VS I've just pressed `Build Revision Helper` and then gone for `Publish Revision Helper`. Now when I actually double-click on `Revision Helper 2.0.application` it always comes up with a small window titled "Launching Application" before the actual Winform appears ...bl**dy annoying as it's not a complicated app, and this is a really powerful pc - you veer come across this before?

Comment: Never seen before, but I don't use ClickOnce. Could [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winformssetup/thread/CD991579-BF49-4BAC-B095-E1F5932A47A0) be of help?

Comment: if you don't use ClickOnce then do you use the code in that link you supplied or do you use some other method for publishing?